# Blurry and vintage feel picture

Tags: blur, vintage

How to take or edit picture like this?
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The image has a very grainy feel to it, if your goal is to achieve that sort of look a simple way would be to boost your ISO.

> As a general rule, the lower the number, the better the quality of the photo. By doubling the ISO, you’re effectively doubling the exposure taken by the camera and, in turn, doubling the digital noise. This noise reduces the detail of a photo by making the image appear grainy and uneven.
>
> Lower number = Lower sensitivity = Finer quality photos

[A simple guide of understanding how ISO works](https://expertphotography.com/understand-iso-4-simple-steps/)